# Resolving Default Instance if no Alias is found in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following container

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>("One");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooTwo>("Two");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooThree>("Three");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooFour>("Four");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooFive>("Five");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooSix>("Six");
```

now when i access it , i use

```
IFoo foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(AliasString);
```

Now the problem is i am getting Alias string from the User, and want to have FooOne returned if the Alias is not among the registered ones e.g
if the Alias is passed as "SEVEN", then it should return FooOne

Is there any way to achieve it ?

NOTE: I don't want to have a loop on container registrants ...

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IsRegistered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660863(v=pandp.20).aspx) method of container:

```
IFoo foo;
if (Container.IsRegistered<IFoo>(AliasString))
{
    foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(AliasString);
}
else
{
    foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>("One");
}
```

To exclude loop-checking you can wrap this to some factory:

```
public class Factory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly HashSet<string> _classes = new HashSet<string>();

    public Factory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    public void Register<TInterface, TClass>(string alias) where TClass : TInterface
    {
        _classes.Add(alias);
        _container.RegisterType<TInterface, TClass>(alias);
    }
    public TInterface Resolve<TInterface>(string alias)
    {
        if (_classes.Contains(alias))
            return _container.Resolve<TInterface>(alias);
        return _container.Resolve<TInterface>("default");
    }
}

var factory = new Factory(container);
factory.Register<IFoo, FooOne>("One");
IFoo foo = factory.Resolve<IFoo>(AliasString);
```

Comment: as i mentioned I dont want to have a loop on container registrants every time,  and .IsRegistered is doing the same :(

Comment: @N.K what the reason don't use a loop?

Comment: @N.K well, all feelings about perfomance must be confirmed by the facts. if you have 7 implementations - it's one way, one million - another. I don't think that 100 is too much to cause perfomance problems, but I don't know your application. You can store in Set or Dictionary all you implementations